# ReactCSSTransitionGroup: transitionAppear doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, jsx, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to appearance/disappearance the notification, but `transitionAppear` doesn't work. I add item (notification popup) to the `onBlur` event. Animation at the time of `leave` works smoothly and at the time of `appear` it just appears abruptly without `transition`. In the React recently, do not swear strongly:D

**P.S.**
*If I add `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` in **`alert.js`** -`appear` works, but `leave` - no.*

**CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/l26j10613q
(on CodeSandbox I used `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` in **`alert.js`**, so `appear` works, but `leave` — no)

**`alert.js:`**

```
export default class Alert extends Component {
  render() {
    const { icon, text } = this.props;
    let classNames = "cards-wrapper-alert";
    return (
     <div className={classNames}>
       <Card zIndex="2">
         <Icon icon={icon} eClass="alert-message-icon"/>
         <Label text={text} fw="fw-medium" fs="fs-14" fc="c-dark"/>
       </Card>
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**`alert.css:`**

```
.alert-appear {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.alert-appear.alert-appear-active {
  max-height: 80px;
  transition: max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.alert-leave {
  max-height: 80px;
}

.alert-leave.alert-leave-active {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

What I do in **`input.js:`**

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
  component={this.prepareComponentForAnimation}
  transitionName="alert"
  transitionEnter={false}
  transitionAppear={true}
  transitionAppearTimeout={400}
  transitionLeaveTimeout={400}>
    {this.state.alert ?
      <Alert icon={this.state.icon} text={this.state.text}/>
    : null}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: on SO RU: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/905396/280567

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or any other reproducible example? It would be really useful.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb, take a look — https://codesandbox.io/s/l26j10613q

Comment: Just a quick guess - it looks like [react-addons-css-transition-group](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-css-transition-group) is deprecated?

Comment: @Arthur I must say this is the most comprehensive reproducible example I've encountered on SO!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to [change your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/mz1knpr288) to reproduce the exact scenario that you've shown in your .gif, by moving `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` to the `Input` component.

After reading the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html#animate-initial-mounting), I found this line which makes sense as to why your `Alert` was not animating when showing up for the first time:

> ReactCSSTransitionGroup provides the optional prop transitionAppear, to add an extra transition phase at the initial mount of the component.

What is happening here is not the initial mount. The `alert` state is set once there is some user interaction on the input.

So, the simple answer to your question is that you need to use the `enter` phase, and not `appear` phase because of the docs that I've posted above.

Comment: Ty! I will test on my server and after that I will hand you a reward!=)